Website to calculate sun elevation on a certain day?
Is there a website that will calculate a chart of the sun's elevation over the course of a certain day?
Something like this:


Here's one https://celestialprogramming.com/Altitude_Graph/index.html

https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/canada/les-coteaux
This one is for my town, but you can select any other place from the menu

You can get that data directly from JPL Horizons. That just gives you raw data in ASCII format, but if you know how to code it's not too hard to convert the Horizons data into a chart.
Here's an example plot for 2024-Jan-1, for the Greenwich observatory.

That plot was created using this Sage / Python script  running on the SageMathCell server. The script mainly uses Python syntax, it just uses Sage to do the plotting (which is actually done by matplotlib).
You can use this script to make elevation plots of any Solar System body, with any major body as the observing center. You can specify the observing location by entering the longitude, latitude, altitude. (The altitude is in kilometres). Or you can give a site ID number: Horizons knows all the standard IAU observatory codes. Or just enter * into the site field for a list. Horizons also has numbered sites on the Moon and Mars.
By default, times are given in UTC, but you can also enter times for other timezones in the start field. For example, 2024-Jun-2 6:00 UT-8. Please see the Horizons manual for details.
There's an option to apply a simple correction for atmospheric refraction, but it's only applicable if Earth is the observing center. My script will crash if you select refracted for other centers.
